# What songs can the bouncing music ball play?

Tags: game-music-identification, zelda-tri-force-heroes

In the lobby of Triforce Heroes, you can run into the walls to make a bouncing music ball drop from the ceiling. When striking the ball, it plays one of many different tunes until it hits the ground and drops some rupees.
What are the songs it can play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all the songs GameXplain found in the full version:

1. The Legend of Zelda Overworld (TLoZ)
2. Wind Waker Title Screen (WW)
3. Clock Town (MM)
4. Realm Overworld (ST)
5. Fairy Fountain (ALttP)
6. Song of Storms / Windmill Hut (OoT)
7. Dark World (ALttP)
8. Fi's Theme (SS)
9. Ballad of the Goddess (SS)
10. Linebeck's Theme (PH)
11. Lon Lon Ranch (OoT)
12. Zelda's Lullaby (ALttP/OoT)
13. Ballad of the Windfish (LA)
14. Madame Couture's Theme (TFH)
15. The Great Sea (PH)
16. Hyrule Field (TP)
17. Skyloft (SS)
18. Saria's Song/Lost Woods (OoT)
19. Lorule Castle (ALBW)
20. Yuga Battle (ALBW)
21. Mother Maiamai's Theme (ALBW)
22. Hilda's Theme (ALBW)
23. Tri Force Heroes Main Theme (TFH)

Source:

Answer (score 3):

As of the demo, the ball can play five different songs:

- Overworld (LoZ);
- Dark World (LTTP);
- Lon Lon Ranch (OoT);
- Clock Town (MM); and
- Lorule Castle (ALBW)

Comment: You should include some sort of note to clarify that these are the songs available in the demo. The ball in the full version of the game will include 23 songs.

Comment: Are there? Oh my

Comment: Yep, according to one of the NPCs in the lobby.